# Sql query combining results

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following:

```
void Main()
{
    // I need to get the below query, but with the newest comment date as well of each post.
    
    
    // Gives me all the posts by the member
    var member_id = 1139;
    var query = (from posts in Ctm_Forum_Posts
                join category in Ctm_Forum_Categories on posts.FK_Categori_ID equals category.Id
                where posts.Archieved == false 
                && posts.Deleted == false 
                && posts.FK_Member_ID == member_id
                select new ForumPostModel(){
                    Id = posts.Id,
                    BodyText = posts.BodyText,
                    Summary = posts.Summary, 
                    Title = posts.Title,
                    Created = posts.Created,
                    Updated = posts.Updated,
                    CategoryName = category.Title,
                });

    // this gives the newest comment date (registration_timestamp) from a specific post with id = 1
    var NewestCommentDate = (from comments in Ctm_Comments
                             join posts in Ctm_Forum_Posts on comments.Page_ID equals posts.Id
                             where posts.Id == 1 && comments.Deleted == false
                             orderby comments.Reqistration_timestamp descending
                             select comments.Reqistration_timestamp).FirstOrDefault();
}

// Model of the result.

public class ForumPostModel{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string BodyText { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LatestCommentTime { get; set; }
}
```

Right now the two queries work, but my problem is the performance sucks,, so im trying to combine the results into a single query, so my load time will be much less.

I tried searching about unions, but have been unable to figure it out.

Comment: Combining will not fix performance.  It will be easier to fix leaving separate.

Comment: wouldn't a single query be better than two?

Comment: Not necessarily.  I would do the WHERE before the join which will improve performance like this : from posts in Ctm_Forum_Posts.Where(posts => where posts.Archieved == false && posts.Deleted == false && posts.FK_Member_ID == member_id)